# 'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type' for inherited model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, asp.net-mvc-layout

I know this question has been asked numerous times, but I haven't found an already-asked question that addresses my problem exactly. My problem is that, for some reason, I am unable to use as a model a type that inherits from the *expected* type.

The exact error I am getting is:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'ShoppingDealsClient.Models.ListViewModel`1[ShoppingDealsClient.Models.Deal]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ShoppingDealsClient.Models.ListViewModel`1[ShoppingDealsClient.Models.BaseResponseModel]'.
```

and I get this error whenever I try to access the page `http://localhost:50548/Home/Deal`.

Let's look at the `Deal.cshtml` page:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deals";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_ListLayout.cshtml";
}
```

All it has is a reference to `_ListLayout.cshtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MenuedLayout.cshtml";
}
@model ShoppingDealsClient.Models.ListViewModel<ShoppingDealsClient.Models.BaseResponseModel>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>
        <span>@ViewBag.Title</span>
        <button class='btn btn-primary pull-right'>+ Add New</button>
    </h1>
    <div>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the `_ListLayout.cshtml` page is expecting a `ListViewModel<BaseResponseModel>` object as its model.

Below is the code where I return the view:

```
public ActionResult Deal()
{
    return View(new ListViewModel<Deal>());
}
```

where `Deal` inherits from `BaseResponseModel`.

As you can see, I am returning the correct type in the `Deal()` method, but I am still getting this type of error. Could there be a problem with my use of `Layout` views? Is there a better way to use partial views that can accept models?

EDIT On My Inheritance

I am intending for this same `_ListLayout` to be reused to eventually display lists of a wide range of different models that all inherit from `BaseResponseModel`. That is why the inheritance I have is necessary.

I am new to MVC development, so if anyone knows of a better way to accomplish, a comment would be helpful :)

Comment: The derived types have overridden methods, and `ListViewModel` uses some reflection on its parameterized type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *lots* of questions that address your problem. Either you just don't recognize it as the same or those answers aren't what you want to hear.

A `ListViewModel<Deal>` is NOT a `ListViewModel<BaseResponseModel>` because `BaseResponseModel` is not covariant.  In the same way, a `Cage<Tiger>` is not a `Cage<Animal>` because you can add a `Rabbit` to a `Cage<Animal>` but not o a `Cage<Tiger>` (at least without horrific results).

Do some research on covariance to see if you need to create a covariant interface or find some other solution to your problem.

An exmnaple of a covariant interface would be something like:

```
public interface IBaseModel<out TModel> where TModel : TBaseResponseModel
```

the constraint is that the interface can only *output* `TModel` objects - it cannot accept any as input (and cannot have any properties that are covariant, like a `List<TModel>`.

So an interface with get-only properties and/or properties that return covariant interfaces (like `IEnumerable<TModel>`) an likely be made covariant.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `output`...are you referring to the return types of the interface's method?

Comment: and based on your answer, I didn't recognize the correct problem in my question - it seems my understanding of the relationships  between objects is shaky

Comment: You are expecting to be able to substitute a `C<A>` for a `C<B>` just because `A` inherits from `B`.  That is _covariance_ and requires limitations on `B` - namely that `B` be a covariant interface.

Comment: And by output, yes I mean the return types of the interface methods.

Comment: If I create a covariant interface like the one you described above, how would I use that for the model of the `_ListLayout`?

Comment: Something like `@model ShoppingDealsClient.Models.ListViewModel<ShoppingDealsClient.Models.IModel>`

Comment: `IModel` expects a type parameter though...which is the problem I am currently having

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `@model ShoppingDealsClient.Models.IBaseModel<ShoppingDealsClient.Models.BaseResponseModel>`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
@model ShoppingDealsClient.Models.ListViewModel<ShoppingDealsClient.Models.BaseResponseModel>
```

Your view expects a model of the above type and you pass an object of type `ListViewModel<Deal>`.

As I can infer from the error message the `Deal` is not a `BaseResponseModel`. If it does make sense the `Deal` to inherit from `BaseResponseModel`, then doing so you would solve your problem. Otherwise you have to alter either the model that your View expects or to alter the model that you pass to your view to the correct one.

Comment: `As I can infer from the error message the Deal is not a BaseResponseModel`

Yeah, I know that....the problem is that `Deal` inherits from `BaseResponseModel`, so I would expect this to work...

Comment: To address your edit: `Deal` *already* inherits from `BaseResponseModel`, but I am still getting this error

Comment: So, since `Deal` inherits from `BaseResponseModel`, why you don't alter the `@model` statement to this one `@model ShoppingDealsClient.Models.ListViewModel<Deal>`? Since `Deal` inherits from `BaseResponseModel` you could access any property (except private that you can't in any way to access) of your model.

Comment: See my edits. I am expecting to reuse this same layout to work with a number of different `BaseResponseModel` subclasses

Comment: Hm...a dirty solution that I could think it would be the following `return ((BaseResponseModel)(new ListViewModel<Deal>()))`. I ma not sure if this does the trick but I have the intuition that it may does :)